# Translate of custom post type slug with WP and WPML

Tags: wordpress

Morning,

I'm using WPML 2.0, the latest free version of the plugin.

The whole website works perfectly however I faced an issue.

I have created custom post type called `works` with `portfolio` slug. Is there any way to translate the slug? Any ideas, suggestions?

Regards,
DaveW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/types/

> Types is the only custom fields and post types plugin that's built multilingual-ready. It plays perfectly with WPML. You'll be able to translate everything, including texts and labels in the WordPress admin and user-content for front-page.

good luck! :)